# WS-Management: The service is configured to reject remote connection requests for this plugin

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I am writing a Powershell script to install SQL Server on remote servers.  I have two VM servers built at the same time, by the same guy, running Windows Server 2019.  They differ slightly in number of CPUs and installed memory, (at my request), but other than that should be identical, although I have installed the application manually on one server.  The process the script follows is this:

1. Create a remote session and a session configuration on the remote server to get around the double hop issue.
2. Close session and start a new one with the newly created session configuration.
3. Mount an ISO from a third server, (hence the need for the session configuration).
4. Run the installation.
5. Unmount the ISO.
6. Close the session

If I run this against one server, (the one I did the manual install on), it works just fine.  If I run it against the second it will create the session configuration, but fails to then create the second remote session.  All the searching I've done comes up with "The WS-Management service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests", but this isn't my issue.  I can connect, and create/update the session configuration, but the second connection attempt fails with the message "The service is configured to **reject remote connection requests for this plugin**", and I can't find any info on this.

Here's the relevant portion of the script:

```
# Start remote session $ServerName
$cred = Get-Credential $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME
$remote = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $cred
$ConfigurationName = "DBAdmin"

# Create configuration on remote server if one doesn't exist, else update it
# (This allows double-hop to installation media)
"Starting remote session ...."
Invoke-Command -Session $remote -ScriptBlock {
    param($configname, [PSCredential]$cred)
    $config = Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name $configname
    if($config) {
        if($config.RunAsUser -ne $cred.UserName) {
            "Updating remote session configuration ...."
            Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name $configname -RunAsCredential $cred
        }
    } else {
        "Creating remote session configuration ...."
        Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name $configname -RunAsCredential $cred
    }
} -ArgumentList $ConfigurationName, $cred
# Stop remote session
Remove-PSSession -Session $remote

### Fails on this next line - on one server only ###
# Run installation on remote machine using configuration
$remote = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName $ConfigurationName

Invoke-Command -Session $remote -ScriptBlock {
    param($path, $params)
    
    # Mount ISO to drive letter
    "Mounting installation ISO ...."
    $isopath = $path + "*.iso"
    $iso = (Get-ChildItem -Path $isopath).Name
    $path += $iso
    $mnt = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $path -PassThru
    $drive = ($mnt | Get-Volume).DriveLetter

    # Check for PID
    if($params.Contains("pid-goes-here")) {
        $pidpath = $drive[0] + ":\x64\DefaultSetup.ini"
        $pidvalue = Get-Content -Path $pidpath | Where-Object {$_ -match "PID="} | ConvertFrom-StringData
        $params = $params.Replace("pid-goes-here", $pidvalue.PID)
        $params = $params.Replace("`"", "")
    }

    # Run installation
    "Running installation ...."
    # Write out command and parameters for testing
    Write-Host ($drive[0] + ":\setup.exe")
    Write-Host $params
    # Uncomment following line to actually run setup
    #Start-Process -FilePath ($drive[0] + ":\setup.exe") -ArgumentList $params -Wait

    # Un-mount ISO
    "Un-mounting ISO ...."
    $mnt = Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath $path
} -ArgumentList $InstallMediaPath, $Parameters
# Stop remote session
"Closing remote session ...."
Remove-PSSession -Session $remote
```

Any ideas as to what I can try?  I've updated group policy from not-configured to enabled for Allow Remote Access, even though I don't think this is the issue, and it didn't help.  This is my first attempt at any serious Powershell scripting, so I might be missing something obvious.

My next step is to run the install manually as I did on the first server, and if it works after that try and figure out what it's doing, as installing manually defeats the purpose of my script!

Thanks!

Comment: It might be your NIC trust scope the adapter is assigned at the OS level, change to `domain` or `private` if it's set to `public`. Also, on server(s) with issue, run PowerShell admin elevated `Enable-PSRemoting -Force -SkipNetworkProfileCheck;`, now retry connection. I'd also confirm connection access via `Enter-PSSession` using the `-Credential` parameter too for troubleshooting.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I did a manual install, which required a restart, and now my script runs. So I didn't have chance to try your suggestions. I'll be getting another server spun up soon and will try on that. I can confirm that Enter-PSSession worked prior to install, and also that I did run Enable-PSRemoting, but not with the profile check switch. Will look in to the NIC trust scope. Just hoping it wasn't as simple as a reboot required before running my script! That would be embarrassing.

Comment: If you are joining to domains, expecting policies to apply, and then those policies open the PS Remoting, etc. that could be it. Same with any AV policies that are applied post some automated checking, etc. For the GPO level stuff, on a DC run `repadmin /syncall /AdeP` after you move the machine to appropriate OU and add to any groups, then run `gpupdate /force` on the domain joined machine, reboot, and then test always when there are issues with new spun up VMs and such. No worries if that's what it is, tag me back, you can always delete your question too if needed.